# M2.2CE - Different weights when ordering different quantities

Tags: magento2.2, product-weight

We have an issue where we have an item that is originally 3 pounds but goes inside an 8-pound box due to sizing. This is fine as we will then set the product to around 8 pounds and be done with it. However, when, say 5 of the same item is ordered on an order, we end up using a different box which essentially changes the weights again to be back to around 3 pounds per item instead of 8 pounds per item when purchased separately.

Example:

```
Order 1: 1 of Item X purchased, product weight comes as 8 pounds.

Order 2: 5 of Item X purchased, product weight should be 3 pounds each, 
totaling 15 pounds, not 40 pounds.
```

Is there any way to attack this type of issue in Magento?

Comment: the requirement is not clear to me.`5 of Item X purchased, product weight should be 3 pounds each, 
totaling 15 pounds, not 42 pounds` How  `42 pounds comes`

Comment: Simply math typo there, sorry! Should be 40 pounds, not 42, and that would just be the 5 x 8 pounds, but since its in a different box when purchasing 5 at once, it would be 3 pounds per item instead of 8 pounds, so the weight gets calculated as 5 x 3 pounds instead of 5 x 8 pounds.